# Can JNI Be Implemented To Use A C++ Class In A DLL To Write A File To Disk?

Tags: java, c++, dll, io, java-native-interface

I coded a C++ class (e.g. JsonWriter) that uses RapidJson C++ library APIs to write formatted JSON files to disk.  I would like to use this class in a Java web solution to do the same thing using JNI.

I tried to use JsonWriter for this purpose by compiling it into a DLL file with the necessary JNI includes and .cpp and companion .h files that can be used by a Java class to interface with JsonWriter's methods at runtime.

Unfortunately, when I run my Java web solution with the deployed DLL and call JsonWriter's methods no JSON file is being written to disk.  I know my Java app is loading and using the classes in the DLL appropriately because the C++ classes in the DLL are outputting debugging statements and returning values to the Java classes that use them.  However, the call to JsonWriter for writing a Json file to disk does not write it and I get no errors either.

Is it not possible to use JNI to invoke a C++ class in a DLL to write a file to disk?

Comment: *because the C++ classes in the DLL are outputting debugging statements* -- What's the issue in using the debugger to debug the DLL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't imagine that's be the case.  Once you call the DLL you're effectively calling native code that isn't under control of the JVM.  My guess would be that the the user doesn't have access to the directory that the DLL is attempting to write to.  IOW, I'm quicker to assume permissions issue on the filesystem.

As far as not getting errors, are you calling the windows GetLastError function?  If for some reason JNI was actually preventing it, I have to believe C++ would still error since it's native code and outside of the domain of the JVM.

Comment: Thanks Brian - since I'm on Windows 10, I confirmed the folder containing my DLL file has "Full Control" permissions for authenticated users (which I am at run time).  However, the JsonWriter C++ class in the DLL is still not writing any output to disk.

Comment: Can you call it from a C++ app and confirm that the DLL is working as expected from there?

Comment: Thanks Brian. I realized that question is a moot point because the DLL was in fact writing to disk but it wasn't writing to the expected location. Instead, it was writing to my Desktop.

Comment: Awesome!  Glad I could help :)